# the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I used `ASP.NET MVC 5.2` and `EF 6` and `.Net 4.6` in Visual studio `2013`.

Iadded `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` `dll` but when I want add this namespace in my project It does not exist.

I just have `System.ComponentModel.Design` namespace in classes.

I have dll in refrences .

whats wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the solution?

Comment: yes I clean and rebuild solution  many times

Comment: Try adding the NuGet package "System.ComponentModel.Annotations", which I believe it's added by default on the MVC non-empty templates

Comment: ok , let me update nuget version to v 3.0

Answer (score 0):

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is not referenced by default in the visual studio templates you have to add the particular reference manually

> Solution explorer -> Add reference -> Select .Net tab -> select
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the list